# Spring cloud Kafka limit message consumption per time unit

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, throttling

I have a consumer application with spring cloud stream. This application is consuming messages from a queue (Kafka), and per each message the app makes 4 different HTTP calls to 4 different servers, one of then very slow (10 seconds to answer). When the queue is full of messages, like 6000, the app crashes because several reasons (1 - netty runs out of direct memory, 2 - we are using reactor and the thread pool gets empty).

Is there some way to limit the consumption velocity on consumer side either through spring-cloud-stream or kafka? Something like maximum messages per seconds would be nice.

Here you can see the configuration for kafka (application.yml)

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: my-cloud-kafka-instance
    admin:
      ssl:
        protocol: SSL
    properties:
      security.protocol: SSL
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: my-group
          destination: my-destination
          content-type: application/json
```

And here is my consumer (in kotlin):

```
@Controller
@EnableBinding(Processor::class)
class MyConsumer(
        myDependendies
) {

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    fun myMethod(
            @Headers headers: Map<String, String>,
            @Payload myMessage: Message
    ) {
        myBussinessLogic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pollable Message Source allows consumers to control consumption rates. For example, to illustrate briefly, we first define an interface:

```
public interface PolledProcessor {

    @Input
    PollableMessageSource destIn();

    @Output
    MessageChannel destOut();

}
```

Use examples:

```
@Autowired
private PolledProcessor polledProcessor;


@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5_000)
public void poll() {
    polledProcessor.destIn().poll(message -> {
        byte[] bytes = (byte[]) message.getPayload();
        String payload = new String(bytes);
        logger.info("Received: " + payload);
        polledProcessor.destOut().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload.toUpperCase())
                .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
                .build());
    });
}
```

Reference resources:

https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/27/spring-cloud-stream-2-0-polled-consumers

Comment: Not a big fan of manually handle the poll process, having the need of working with ByteArray... but this solve our consumer issue, thank you very much!